# How to make fullscreen Ionic Capacitor App?

Tags: fullscreen, capacitor

Capacitor have in docs tutorial about screen orientation (https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/guides/screen-orientation#screen-orientation-in-your-capacitor-app), but how to toggle app to fullscreen? Cordova had built-in settings in config.xml, but in capacitor I dont know how to make it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [fullscreen plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-full-screen) from Cordova (still working with Capacitor)

```
npm install cordova-plugin-fullscreen
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/android-full-screen
ionic cap sync
```

Then in your App.tsx

```js
AndroidFullScreen.isImmersiveModeSupported()
  .then(() => AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode())
  .catch(console.warn);
```

Try it on your phone

```
ionic cap run android --external -livereload
```

This will hide both the status bar and the navigation buttons.
If user swipe down where the status bar was, it will smoothly show it for 2 seconds.

Comment: I get error saying "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
.../node_modules/(awesome-cordova-plugins/android-full-screen/index.js(16)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to hide the status bar.
In that case you can use the official Capacitor Status Bar plugin to hide the status bar. See https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar#hide.

```js
import { StatusBar } from '@capacitor/status-bar';

const hideStatusBar = async () => {
  await StatusBar.hide();
};
```

Comment: in addition to hiding the status bar, if you want to also remove the navigation bar from the bottom, there is a setting to use gestures instead. see also https://www.answertabs.com/remove-or-hide-bottom-navigation-bar-with-buttons-on-android/ - this has nothing to do with capacitor.

Comment: for me I want it different. is there a setting I can force the screen to respect the notification bar's position?